# Generate a Unity 2d Game Object Dynamically within the different devices screen bounds

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, screen-resolution

I am new to unity and I am developing a game where I wish to create a game object dynamically. My problem is how do I calculate the random position for the game object so that it remains within the screen on different android devices. Here is something I have tried, but is my approach correct? Will this give me a proper random position on all android and iOS devices?

```
//Calculate the screen width and screen height
screenheight = Camera.main.orthographicSize * 2.0f;
screenwidth = screenheight * Screen.width / Screen.height;

//get a random number in width of the screen
float randomX = Random.Range(-screenwidth / 2, screenwidth / 2);

//get a random number in height of the screen
float randomY = Random.Range(-screenheight / 2, screenheight / 2);
```

Now the game objects position will be (randomX, randomY).

Comment: The proper tag for Unity3D is unity3d.

Comment: I don't have any experience with android, but why are you using `-screenwidth / 2` why not just a random number between 0 and `Screen.width` ?

Comment: @ILiveForVR Because the object is not getting instantiated in screen space. It gets instantiated in world space.

Comment: @White Falcon As for the correctness, you should be able to tell us :) Instantiate a thousand cubes with that code on different viewport sizes and see. It seems like it was written correctly.